# ASP.NET DATA TABLE Traverse Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the Data table a output from my DataAccess Layer.

In My Datatable I am getting users Name,Number,Qualification

I want to assign a users name,number,qualification to a textbox for a particular user id,

How can i do that.

Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you got datatable dt from the DAL

Then

```
var row = from t in dt
          where t["userId"]='userid'
          select t;

since you got row related to a user now you can use it to assign to the textboxs

 txtName.Text = row["Name"]
```

Comment: first if you like the solution then increse vote count , little up down button starting with any answer then when you mouse hover than you will see how to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

assuming the datatable has 1 row:

```
DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
textbox1.text = row["Name"];
textbox2.text = row["Number"];
```

and so on

if there are multiple rows in the datatable, you need to select the row with that particular used id

```
DataRow row = table.Select("ID=" + UserID.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay attention to NULL values and number of rows.

```
if (table.Rows.Count == 1)
{
  DataRow row = table.Rows[0];

  NameTextBox.Text = row.IsNull("name") ? string.Empty : row["name"];
  NumberTextBox.Text = row.IsNull("number") ? string.Empty : row["number"];
}
else
{
// Deal with no rows from DL
}
```

Using ternary operator makes you sure, you delete content of TextBoxes in case you reload row within already filled up page.

Also you may consider to used typed dataset, and access to columns will be generated by xsd.exe.